# scroll to content in overflow div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this content in page 
on some action i want to scroll to id# using javascript/jquery.
eg on button click scroll id6 div to top within DIV not page.

This code is not working

```
$('#id5').scrollTop($("#id5")[0].scrollHeight);

<div id="t1" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
<div id="id1">What is Lorem Ipsum?</div>
<div id="id2">What is Lorem Ipsum?</div>
<div id="id3">What is Lorem Ipsum?</div>
<div id="id4">What is Lorem Ipsum?</div>
<div id="id5">What is Lorem Ipsum?</div>
<div id="id6">What is Lorem Ipsum?</div>
so on....
</div>
```

Comment: You must click to '#id5' and scroll to another '#element'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of each div element should big enough for the scrolling effect, otherwise you will not see anything.Check the code below, you will understand how it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".scroll").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var hash = this.hash;
        $("html,body").animate({
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800);
  })

});
```

```css
ul > li{ list-style:none; }
.box{ height:500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
 <div class="box" id="cl1">
   <a class="scroll" href="#cl2">Click Here</a>
 </div>
</li>
<li>
 <div class="box" id="cl2">
   <a class="scroll" href="#cl1">Click Here</a>
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: $("html,body") to $("#Div_ID") then working fine for me.